# When/After I am scolded by my mother, I go to bed and fall asleep late, usually past 10 p.m. - differences in meaning?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, present-tense

I understand "after" can express habitual or repetitive events, but I still feel like "after" is different from "whenever."

When "after" is used, it makes me feel that the event happens regularly or maybe daily. However, "when" doesn't mean that way. Can anyone shed light on this?

**Example 1**

> Whenever I am scolded by my mother, I go to bed and fall asleep late, usually past 10 p.m.

Example 1 feels like I am scolded by my mother, maybe once in a while, and it is not a routine or a regular event.

**Example 2**

> After I am scolded by my mother, I go to bed and fall asleep late, usually past 10 p.m.

Example 2 feels like I am scolded by my mother every day, and it is basically a routine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I agree with you that using **after** makes it sound as though the scolding is a routine, or at least a frequent, occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrent aspect is conveyed by **am scolded** and is present in equal measure, in my opinion, in both examples.

**after** refers to the events chronologically, one thing occurs and then it is followed by the other.

**when** and **whenever** refer to the events as coinciding.

The coinciding events are more likely to be understood as cause-and-effect than the sequential events.

Perhaps there is an implication with **when** and **whenever** that the speaker doesn't feel much like doing anything else after being scolded.  **after**, in focusing on the chronological sequence of the events, seems less emotional, almost as though the speaker is shrugging off the scolding and that may reinforce the notion that it is a routine occurence.